# Resolving Country + State via lat/lng

Tags: geolocation, geo, geonames

I want to be able to resolve the country and state via latitude and longitude GPS values.
It should work in ms!

I thought of using geonames db and the following C# lib:
https://github.com/RobThree/NGeoNames

It indeed works, but the memory required for storing the "allCountries" db is quite expensive => around 10GB (of course the init loading time is long as well).
I tried to shrink this db and to create my own db, while taking only lat, lng, country and admin code(for states) as well as taking only items which fits the country, state, region **feature codes**, from here : https://www.geonames.org/export/codes.html

It seems to work and the db is very small around 10 mb on disk. 
But I'm afraid that filtering via the feature codes might hurt the accuracy.
How can I be sure that it is accurate enough? 
Any other already prepared db like this?

Or other solution than the geonames db?

Also, calling Google API as alternative might be to expensive on my end.

Answer (score 0):

If daly reqest are limited to 2500 You can use free apis like [OpenCage API](http://opencagedata.com)
.Its same as google API
 or As you request [Loc2Country](https://github.com/soorajb/loc2country) can used (its quite fast). And there are Reverse geocoders if you like : [locationIQ](https://locationiq.com/docs), [ArcGis](https://www.arcgis.com/index.html)

Comment: Due to rough requirement, each such resolve should not take more than 100ms at most. The api calls to any service won't work in such rate (latency and so...). so the best solution for us is to maintain such a solution in-house, for example by using the geonames dbs